# How to automount hard disks without the need for password at login?

Tags: automount, kubuntu

I want my Kubuntu to auto mount my hard disks at login without the need for password. 
I tried it through System settings -> removable media and checked "Enable automount removable media". But at the moment i log in Kdesudo asks for password for all the hard drive at once.

I want it without any password. How can i do that ?

Answer (score 3):

Check out [PySDM](http://pysdm.sourceforge.net/).

> PySDM is a Storage Device Manager that
>   allows full customization of hard disk
>   mountpoints without manually access to
>   fstab. It also allows the creation of
>   udev rules for dynamic configuration
>   of storage devices.
>   [image]

Answer (score 1):

Download ntfs-3g config from Kpackagekit

Comment: that helped. How did you understand that the disks were ntfs ?

Comment: i asumed they were

Answer (score 0):

Or edit the /etc/fstab file

http://cybernightlife.wikidot.com/fstab-explained

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me to mount an NTFS driver under Kubuntu. It was a GUID partitioned multi TB drive, so some standard tools like fdisk did not like it, but this worked. :)

```
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda4 /mnt/bigboy
```