# Automounting partitions on 1TB external hard disk

Tags: automount, dolphin, unmount, eject

I am on Kubuntu 12.04.

I have five labelled `ext4` partitions on an external removable 1 TB external USB hard drive.

When the drive is plugged in, a box pops up, asking me what I want to do for each partition. If I elect to use the `dolphin` file manager, it mounts the relevant partition on `/media/LABEL` where `LABEL` is the label of that partition. Interestingly, the directories on `/media` disappear after the external drive is ejected.

To enable automated backups, I want to find out if the mounting can be done automatically without having to click on the popup box to select the `dolphin` file manager? Essentially, I wish to:

1. automount each partition on USB plugin on `/media/LABEL` as before where the directories under `/media` are created automatically on the fly; and
2. On ejection, automatically unmount partitions and remove the directories under `/media`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://forums.opensuse.org/english/get-technical-help-here/applications/446636-mounting-removable-device-without-having-open-dolphin.html#post2225116) should be the answer to your question.

> Under device notifier settings there is an option to select a particular device, which has been previously mounted, and set it to 'Automount on Attach'.

If this solution shouldn't be sufficient (e.g. because Kubuntu still requires root permissions), you can also try [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20572/how-to-automount-hard-disks-without-the-need-for-password-at-login) thread. [PySDM](http://pysdm.sourceforge.net/) looks a great tool.

Comment: Thank you. The solution you have given using `System Settings` -> `Removable Devices` is perfect and works for me. Those who are not faint-hearted could also look at these links: [1](http://superuser.com/questions/194178/arch-linux-cant-auto-mount-removable-storage-device) and [2](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udev#Auto_mounting_USB_devices).