# Partition not loading automatically - Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, bash

So I store my websites on a partition of my laptops hard drive. Programs and my bash scripts say that this partition does not exist, until I personally open the partition up by clicking the icon on the left side.

I am not sure why that is, and then how I could fix it so it either auto loads on startup or my bash script automatically loads it.

Comment: Similar problem to [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/144747/automounting-partitions-on-1tb-external-hard-disk)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `blkid` to get the UUID for the partition, then add a line to `/etc/fstab` to tell the system where you'd like it mounted. You will find advice on doing that in many places, [such as here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18229/how-can-i-automount-my-hard-disk-partitions?rq=1)